# javascript .filter only matches first array item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of ObectID's that I am getting back from my server. I want to take that array and filter all of the projects that match those ObjectID's I have tried to map the array of ObjectID's first then use a .filter to match  all the projects that meet that condition; however it only filters the first item in the array.

Here is my filter method, but as stated above it only matches the first ObjectId in the array, even though there mroe than one in the array.

```
    var projects = [{ 
     accountableStaff: ["1", "2"]
     contact: "3"
     district: "Texas-32"
}]



const foundProjects = projects.filter(
    p => p.accountableStaff == match.params.id
  );
```

Comment: "even though there mroe than one in the array." Please make more than one element in the array then. You're also using `==` to compare arrays, which doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is find any record where the array `accountableStaff` contains the `match.params.id`. For that you can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var projects = [{ 
     accountableStaff: ["1", "2"],
     contact: "3",
     district: "Texas-32"
}]

var match = {params:{id:"1"}};

const foundProjects = projects.filter(
    p => p.accountableStaff.includes(match.params.id)
  );
  
console.log(foundProjects)
```

Comment: Thanks @JamieC that was the key. I will mark the answer as correct once it allows me to.